# OData ignore certain properties unless explicitly stated to be returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have this model with following attributes. (Simplified)

```
public class Blog {
   private string Code { get; set; }
   private string Name { get; set; }
   private byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

When I make a request to the OData URL for ex: http://localhost/api/odata/Blog, I want only Code and Name properties to be returned, ignoring the Image. And if I make
a request something like http://localhost/api/odata/Blog?$select=(Code,Name,Image) then I want the Image to be returned. How can I make this work?
Using attributes like `[IgnoreDataMember]` makes it unavailable for OData query to be accessed, therefore it is not a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, probably properties of the Blog class are public, not private.
I had a similar scenario and resolve it by implementing a custom serializer:
Serializer provider class:

```
public class MyODataSerializerProvider : DefaultODataSerializerProvider
{
    MyResourceSerializer myResourceSerializer;
    public MyODataSerializerProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        myResourceSerializer = new MyResourceSerializer(this);
    }

    public override ODataEdmTypeSerializer GetEdmTypeSerializer(IEdmTypeReference edmType)
    {
        if (edmType.IsEntity())
        {
            return myResourceSerializer;
        }
        return base.GetEdmTypeSerializer(edmType);
    }
}
```

Serializer class:

```
public class MyResourceSerializer : ODataResourceSerializer
{
    public MyResourceSerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider) : base(serializerProvider) { }

    public override ODataResource CreateResource(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, ResourceContext resourceContext)
    {
        var resource = base.CreateResource(selectExpandNode, resourceContext);
        if (selectExpandNode.SelectAllDynamicProperties)
        {
            resource.Properties = resource.Properties.Where(p => p.Name != "Image");
        }
        return resource;
    }
}
```

And configuration of course:

```
routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("OData", "odata", b =>
                {
                    b.AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => edmModel);
                    var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
                    //Workaround for https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1622
                    conventions.Insert(0, new AttributeRoutingConvention("OData", app.ApplicationServices, new DefaultODataPathHandler()));
                    //Custom Convention
                    b.AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, a => conventions);
                    b.AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, typeof(ODataSerializerProvider), sp => new MyODataSerializerProvider(sp));
                });
```